# on passing 2 datetime values using json.stringify to controller with ajax call first one is passed in datetime format but second one becomes null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am trying to pass multiple parameters including 2 datetime type parameters using json.stringify() method through ajax call to mvc controller jsonresult type action method.
All paramters values are passed successfully. From 2 datetime type parameters 1st value is passed successfully but 2nd parameter value becomes null!

below is my code.

javascript code:

```
    var MobileNumber = $('#MobileNumber').val() == "" ? 0 : $("#MobileNumber").val();
    var FromDate = $('#FromDate').val() == "" ? 0 : $("#FromDate").val();
    var FromTime = $('#FromTime').val() == "" ? 0 : $("#FromTime").val();
    var ToDate = $('#ToDate').val() == "" ? 0 : $("#ToDate").val();
    var ToTime = $('#ToTime').val() == "" ? 0 : $("#ToTime").val();

$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Merchant/GetRejectedMerchantTransactions")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ mobileNumber: MobileNumber, fromDate: FromDate, fromTime: FromTime, toDate: ToDate, toTime: ToTime }),
        success: function (data) {
        $('#statusBox').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').show(500, function () {
                                        $('#statusMessage').html(data.Message);
                                    });
                                }
        }
    });
```

and controller code is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetRejectedMerchantTransactions(string mobileNumber, DateTime? fromDate, string fromTime, DateTime? toDate, string toTime)
{
     List<MerchantTransactions> lstMerchantTransactions = new List<MerchantTransactions>();
        try
        {
            string  shortFromDate = "";
            string  shortToDate = "";
            string fromFinalDate = "";
            string toFinalDate = "";

            if (fromDate.HasValue && fromTime.Length > 1)
            {
                shortFromDate = fromDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                fromFinalDate = shortFromDate + " " + fromTime;
            }

            if (toDate.HasValue && toTime.Length > 1)
            {
                shortToDate = toDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                toFinalDate = shortToDate + " " + toTime;
            }

            List<TransactionStatus> lstTransactionStatus = GetTransactions();
            TransService.TransServiceClient transServiceClient = new TransService.TransServiceClient();
            TransService.GetTransactionsRequest getTransactionsRequest = new TransactionService.GetTransactionsRequest
            {
                MobileNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(mobileNumber),
                FromDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromFinalDate) ? fromDate : Convert.ToDateTime(fromFinalDate),
                ToDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(toFinalDate) ? toDate : Convert.ToDateTime(toFinalDate)
            };
}
```

i have also tried by changing the parameters name but it gives same result.

Comment: What are the values, and what if the culture on your server? (and what are you attempting to do by setting the values to `0` if they are `null` (`0` cannot be converted to a `DateTime`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke kindly check the controller action code in asked question. i have updated it for your referemces.

Comment: You controller code has got nothing to do with it. You have said the value of `fromDate` is passed OK but the value of `toDate` is not. SO its the code in your view which is the issue (and we have no idea what `var ToDate = $('#ToDate').val() == "" ? 0 : $("#ToDate").val();` returns or why in the world you convert it to `0` if the textbox is empty (which makes no sense at all)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by applying new Date() javascript function for all datetime type values in my .cshtml file.

like

var FromDate = $('#FromDate').val() == "" ? 0 : new Date($("#FromDate").val());
var FromTime = $('#FromTime').val() == "" ? 0 : new Date($("#FromTime").val());